# AWSCodeCommit: ReadOnly is available, but not FullAccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-codecommit

I am trying to setup a Git Repo on an AWS Gov. Cloud by following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository-existing.html).

As part of the instructions, I need to add Permissions "AWSCodeCommitFullControl" to a user.  When I try to find the policy in "Filter Policies", I can find AWSCodeCommitReadOnly, but not AWSCodeCommitFullAccess.

Because CodeCommitReadOnly is available, I'm confident that FullAccess must be as well.  But it isn't coming up in my searches.

[image]

Can you tell me why? and how to get FullAccess to CodeCommit?

Comment: Strange, AWSCodeCommitFullAccess is [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html#managed-policies) to exist. You may wish to contact GovCloud customer support.

Comment: @abelenky If the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying Thanks :)

Comment: @MLu:  Check my profile:  I have nearly 50,000 on S.E.  I understand how it works; but that answer did not solve my problem.

Comment: @abelenky No offence mate! :) I didn't hear back, how could I know if it helped or not? Never mind, I'm sure you have solved it in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

You may be restricted by **[IAM Permissions Boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html)** that restrict the policies you can assume or delegate to others. You'll need to contact your account admin to change your *Permissions boundaries* to give you access to the `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess` policy.